# DB2 10.1 table data copy to IBM VSE 7.4 table

Tags: db2, database-replication, zos

We have one application where we have db2 10.1 as database.
Now one requirement came in which we need to interface few tables to HOST which is on IBM DB2 VSE 7.4
I tried to execute load command with client option but it give "SQL1325N  The remote database environment does not support the command or one
of the command options." error. 
command is :"D:\tempdata>db2 load client from  app.tbl of ixf
 insert into host.tbl"
Many post says that its not allow to use load from 10.1 to VSE Z/OS.

Another option I tried is import but its too slow and we need to delete records every time as truncate is not available.

Replication can be think for option but we would like to avoid replication.

Can anyone suggest way to achieve this. Load can be use or not?

Answer (score 0):

It seems its not allow to use load from remote machine. But wondering what is use of CLIENT option in load then.

Finally we decided to use import utility after deleting HOST DB2 records. In that we need to execute delete and import command on part of table. If we try to import or delete big table at one go it give error of log file size full.

Hope this will help.